# Why do we customize UINavigationBar's barTintColor exactly in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, appdelegate

Somebody writes this kind of code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Status bar white font
    self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

but it doesn't work, updating it in AppDelegate really works, but why it doesn't work from viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change navigation bar background colour then use below code

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red // set what ever color that you wanr.
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this :**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set these properties in XIB/Storyboard. No need to set it in every controller.

If you want to set it from view controller so you need to `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = typeyourcolor.`

Navigation bar is the property of navigation controller not the view controller.

Comment: If You r new to Swift than first study swift from apple developer portal. than go to tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change navigation bar background colour then use below code

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
```

and If you want to change navigation bar Item colour then use below code

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
```